# Are both csrf tokens and captcha needed?

Tags: forms, security, language-agnostic

Can someone confirm this: do I need to provide both a CSRF token and a Captcha in a submission form, or do the two more or less serve the same function (one can be used instead of the other)?

Comment: This is a good question,  it gets at the fundamentals of what CSRF is.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A captcha can be used instead of a CSRF token.  This is covered in the [OWASP CSRF Prevention Guide](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet).  A Captcha is considered to be a stronger form of CSRF prevention than a token or referer check because it is more difficult to bypass with XSS - but still possible. So long as the captcha cannot be replayed by a different browser than what loaded the captcha.

Any SOP bypass may be used to read the Capthca's challenge-response and feed it to an attacker to solve in order to complete the request. Even in this attack scenario, a CSRF token wouldn't help you, and a Captcha is still more difficult to exploit but not impossible.

Comment: +1.  You only **need** a CSRF token if you are not displaying a Captch image on a form (for example, if you let logged-in users submit without requiring captcha)...

Comment: @ircmaxell  well yes,  I thought that was implied.

Comment: @jblue happy to help.  I think this is a good question because it gets at the heart of what CSRF really is.

Comment: There are CAPTCHA methods that don't display an image, and rather use javascript to ensure a browser is on the other end (see http://samsaffron.com/archive/2011/10/04/Spam+bacon+sausage+and+blog+spam+a+JavaScript+approach). If this kind of CAPTCHA is used, you should also have CSRF token separately, because in the case of CSRF there IS a browser and a user in the other end which runs the javascript perfectly.

Comment: @Iravanchi  Using javascirpt like this is not a "completely automated Turing test to tell computers and humans apart",  it is "security through obscurity".

Answer (score 0):

Yup I was wrong. Both captcha and token are session-bound.

However I still see not much sense in this question.
You cannot use CAPTCHA for the every form on the site. It will drive users crazy and away.
Thus, why not to have a token for the every form by default and CAPTCHA for selected ones?

Comment: Requiring interactive user input prevents XSRF; Because captchas require interactive user input, they can be used to prevent XSRF, just like tokens.

Comment: If it’s a public form, use reCap, otherwise use whatever authentication service you’re using

Answer (score 0):

The above suggests the answer is "no".

But in reading about CSRF tokens compared to CAPTCHA it's worth looking into this, which says:

**"CAPTCHA does not prevent cross-site request forgery (CSRF)":**

https://blog.detectify.com/2017/12/06/captcha-csrf/

Comment: What about to add Google Recaptcha V3 validation on each form?